# How to send a POST request with JSON in body from python to asp.net?

Tags: python, asp.net

I want make a POST request from a python scrypt to asp.net api.

```
requests.post(apiUrl, data={'key': 'value'})
```

This is just a simple request for testing purpose

My action from api controller

```
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("/api/test")]
    public  ActionResult PostAsync(object entity)
    {
        return Ok();
    }
```

again..just for test.
To receive the request I should add the

```
            services.Configure<ApiBehaviorOptions>(options =>
        {
             options.SuppressInferBindingSourcesForParameters = true;
        });
```

in Startup.cs
With all of that, my action is hit by the entity is just an empty object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using the `json=` instead of `data=` argument to `post`.

**Python:**

```
import requests

reqUri = 'http://localhost:51415/weatherforecast'
result = requests.post(reqUri, json={'key':'value'})
print(result)
```

**ASP Net Core Controller:**

```
namespace NetCoreTestAPI.Controllers
{
    [ApiController]
    [Route("[controller]")]
    public class WeatherForecastController : ControllerBase
    {
        [AllowAnonymous]
        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Create(object msgBody)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(msgBody.ToString());
            WeatherForecast retval = new WeatherForecast();
            return new OkObjectResult(retval);
        }
    }
}
```

**Result @ Server:**

```
Route matched with {action = "Create", controller = "WeatherForecast"}. Executing controller action with signature Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.IActionResult Create(System.Object) on controller NetCoreTestAPI.Controllers.WeatherForecastController (NetCoreTestAPI).
{"key": "value"}
```

**Result @ Python Client:**

```
<Response [200]>
```

**EDIT:**
Another option if you want to continue to use the `data=` parameter is to mark your ASP.NET Controller Action with the `[FromForm]` attribute.  From [the docs](https://requests.kennethreitz.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#more-complicated-post-requests) on `requests`:

> Typically, you want to send some form-encoded data — much like an HTML form. To do this, simply pass a dictionary to the data argument. Your dictionary of data will automatically be form-encoded when the request is made

For this to work, you'll need to create a receiving class in ASP.NET for the Controller to deserialize into.  This works fine:

```
public class TestObject
{
    public string key { get; set; }
}

[AllowAnonymous]
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Create([FromForm] TestObject msgBody)
{
    Console.WriteLine(msgBody.ToString());
    WeatherForecast retval = new WeatherForecast();
    return new OkObjectResult(retval);
}
```